# How to override this parent function?

Tags: wordpress-theming

This function in parent theme I can't override it!

```
add_action( 'header_menu', 'oners_sidebars' );
function oners_sidebars(){
    echo '<a href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Sidebars: ', 'Oners' ) . '</a>';
}
```

I use this but its not working:

```
function my_addition () {
    echo '<a href="#">' . esc_html__( 'New Text: ', 'Oners' ) . '</a>';
}

function myn_theme_setup () {
    remove_action( 'header_menu', 'oners_sidebars', 1000 );
    add_action( 'header_menu', 'my_addition', 1000 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myn_theme_setup' );
```

What would I do to override this using my child theme?

Please help me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just remove the unwanted action in `init`?

```
function prefix_remove_oners_sidebars(){

    remove_action ('header_menu', 'oners_sidebars');

}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_remove_oners_sidebars' );
```

As far as I know, wordpress do not have a built-in action hook named `header_menu`. You may take a look at your parent theme for:

```
do_action( 'header_menu' );
```

So you may find where it has been hooked, so you may remove that hook, replacing the `init` in my snippet with the appropriate hook.